# Swift/XCode - Select ANOTHER using ImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am wondering how can I select multiple images using the `ImagePickerController`.

However, I don't wish to select multiple images within the `ImagePickerController` controller. Rather, my app is set where the user selects an `imageView` (they all have a `tapGestureRecogniser`). There are 10. So whenever a user taps a certain `imageView`, I would like the image to be applied to the selected `imageView`.

However, it keeps overriding the first `imageView`.

How can I resolve this matter?

EDIT---

So imagine these are my imageViews:

[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ]

I tap the third one and I select an image. The image should then be applied to the third imageView. And I can then decide to select the first imageView and add another image etc.

I hope this makes sense.

EDIT x 2 - My code:

```
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSelectedImage))
            selectedImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            selectedImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     func handleSelectedImage() {

            let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            pickerController.delegate = self
            pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]
            pickerController.allowsEditing = true
            pickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            pickerController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self as! UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
            pickerController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = selectedImage
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add a Picture", message: "Choose From", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

            let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
                pickerController.sourceType = .camera
                self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            let photosLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photos Library", style: .default) { (action) in
                pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

            let savedPhotosAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Saved Photos Album", style: .default) { (action) in
                pickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
                self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

            let videoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Videos", style: .default) { (action) in

                pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
                pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
            alertController.addAction(photosLibraryAction)
            alertController.addAction(savedPhotosAction)
             alertController.addAction(videoAction)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)



            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
            return .none

        }


extension AddPostViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            chosenImage = image
            selectedImage.image = image
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "returnHome", sender: nil)
            })
        }



    }
```

Comment: can you please share your code for the class where you are using ImagePickerController and setting the image to imageView?

Comment: @Malik I have attached my code along with the tapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Your code didn't show where you were setting the image to imageView. Anyways, I have posted an answer with general idea to get you started in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use your imageView's tag property along with a variable to record which imageView made the call. Mentioned below is a rough outline.

- Create a variable (say `selectedImageView`)
- Set the tag property of your imageViews from 1-5
- When an `imageView` makes a call to open the `imagePickerController`, set `selectedImageView = imageView.tag`
- When an image is picked, check the value for `selectedImageView` and set the image to the `imageView` with the same tag